# Java application running but nothing else

Tags: java, netbeans-8

What you see here is one of my two applications, this one being used to create classes and variables and the second to *get* information from it and display it.

```
package ch7;


import java.util.Calendar;

public class Dealership {

// public static final class variables

public static final int YEAR_STARTED = 1995;
public static final String COMPANY_NAME = "The Rusty Lemon";
public static final String COMPANY_URL = "www.TheRustyLemon.com";
public static final String COMPANY_ADDRESS = 
            "123 Rustbelt Road, Somewhere, SomeState, 12345";
public static final String COMPANY_SLOGAN = 
                    "Many parts of our cars run great!";
public static final double STANDARD_MARKUP = 0.50;
    public static final String COMPANY_EMAIL = "contact@therustylemon.com";


// public static methods
    public static int getYearsInBusiness () {
        int yearsOperating = 0;
        int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR); 
        yearsOperating = currentYear - YEAR_STARTED;
        return yearsOperating;
    }

public static String getCompanyBanner () {
    return COMPANY_NAME + "\n(Selling rusty lemons since " + 
        YEAR_STARTED + ")\n" + COMPANY_ADDRESS + "\n" +
        COMPANY_URL + "\n" + COMPANY_SLOGAN + "\n";
}

public static double getRetailPrice (double dealerCost, 
                        double cleaningCost) {
    double markup = dealerCost * STANDARD_MARKUP;
    return dealerCost + cleaningCost + markup;
}

static String COMPANY_EMAIL() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

Here's the second bit of code. Now when I run this, it will build successfully and run but I won't get anything in terms of output, not even if I do something as simple as

```
System.out.println("hi");
```

nothing, I honestly cannot figure out why in the heavens this could be happening.

```
public class Rusty1
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String message1 = Dealership.getCompanyBanner();
    int message2 = Dealership.getYearsInBusiness();
    String message3 = Dealership.COMPANY_EMAIL();
    System.out.print(message1);
    System.out.print("We've been operating now for " + message2 + " years! To talk to one of our sales people, send an email to" + message3);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an exception when you call `Dealership.COMPANY_EMAIL()` in your main method.

```
static String COMPANY_EMAIL() {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Exception trace in netbeans:

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at javaapplication1.Dealership.COMPANY_EMAIL(Dealership.java:46)
    at javaapplication1.Rusty1.main(Rusty1.java:18)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: Are you sure? I add the exception output for netbeans in output console. Is there really nothing?

Comment: @Scurie DS i agree i just didn't called the Dealership.COMPANY_EMAIL(); and also deleted (message[variable] from output) and then ok.Also what you expect when you alone Throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your method like this:

```
static String COMPANY_EMAIL() {

 if(COMPANY_EMAIL==null)
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
else
    return COMPANY_EMAIL;

}
```

So if the email doesn't exist or isn't supported then throw the exception.

Also this exception is making problems to your program and i recommend you to use the method like this:

```
static String COMPANY_EMAIL() {

  if(COMPANY_EMAIL==null || COMPANY_EMAIL.equals(""))
      return ("Email Function Not supported yet."); //return not supported
 else
     return COMPANY_EMAIL;    //return original email

}
```